# Asynchronously loading data in ngTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am fetching huge set of data to display in ngTable at a time , but i want to fetch data by making service call on each page click rather than fetching it at once .

I have tried to do that by modifying code in the library making service call on each page click and assign the new data set to the ngTable param , but  each time I assign new data the pagination is made according to the current data length , which should on the base of total records present in the DB

Thnaks

Comment: Send `total length of data` through _api_ and set total value. You do this by calling `NgTableParams.total()`. Refer http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/mJoGPE (From documentation)

Comment: it will help you--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805734/loading-json-via-ajax-with-ngtable-parameters

Comment: NgTableParams.total(data.length) helps to populate the page numbers only ,  but this won`t load data of individual page on api call

Comment: You can bind event to page numbers and then update the data in `tableParams` after making api call..

Comment: @RayonDabre i have already tried it , but when ever i update the data on page click data starts inserting from the first page itself  not in the current page only. For example if i click on the page 2 and total records fetched 10 , where the page count is 10 then this records are placed in the first page itself and no records showing in the 2nd page

Comment: You need to update your server side logic for that..also send page number and count in your `http` request..